# Is it possible to access the internal elements of an embedded Flash object via a scripting language?

Tags: javascript, python, flash

I would like to be able to access all the components of say a Flash image gallery on someone else's site. I want to be able to find the **images**, **image coordinates**, **action script code**, **audio files**, **video**, etc. I do not want to manipulate these elements, I just want to view them and their related information.

**Is this possible via scripting languages like Ruby, Python or Javascript?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if (and only if) your application domain is the same.

Comment: You load the swfs as objects into your flash app.

Comment: Best way is if they open up a ExternalInterface for your javascript to use. But this would require them to help you. Another option is to decompile their swf and find/use any code/images you want to use. Another option is reverse engineer there code with something like charles web proxy

Comment: if you have loaded the flash movie into the page through the same flash application - then you can inspector and manipulate the date within the child flash movie.

Comment: Sean what do you mean by 'application domain' ?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html

Comment: It's a security mechanism employed to allow same domain elements to talk with eachother.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. Not like you can examine the DOM of a webpage. You can download and decompile the swf, but you may or may not be able to get all the info you want out.